# How to open new activity that contain RecyclerView and CardView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I created a project that use **RecyclerView** and **CardView** (for PointOfInterest). These 5 activities are relate to each other :

1. PointOfInterest.java
2. PlacesAdapter.java
3. Places.java
4. layout_poi.xml
5. activity_point_of_interest.xml

Meanwhile in **activity_main.xml** I design the Main Menu together with some buttons. One of the button named **Rapid Penang** (id: rapid_btn). I call an activity of Rapid Penang (from **MainActivity.java**) like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button_for_rapid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // to call Rapid Penang class
        button_for_rapid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rapid_btn);
        button_for_rapid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openRapid();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openRapid()
    {
        Intent intent_rapid = new Intent(this, RapidPenang.class);
        startActivity(intent_rapid);
    }

}
```

RapidPenang consist of only one activity and it is success. But when I try to do exactly the same to PointOfInterest activites (as mention above), suddenly the app were crashed.

This is how I try to open PointOfInterest activites from a button in MainMenu called Point Of Interest:

```
private Button button_for_poi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // to call Point Of Interest class
    button_for_poi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.poi_btn);
    button_for_poi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openPOI();
        }
    });
}

public void openPOI()
{
    Intent intent_poi = new Intent(this, PointOfInterest.class);
    Intent intent_poi2 = new Intent(this, PlacesAdapter.class);
    Intent intent_poi3 = new Intent(this, Places.class);
    startActivity(intent_poi);
}
```

Comment: Please show what is shown in Logcat

Comment: "...that contain RecyclerView and CardView" - what has this to do with starting an Activity. It just needs and Intent to start an Activity (irrespective of what it contains).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your activity is define in Android manifest file and then call

```
            StartActivity(new Intent(getApplicationcontext(),RapidPenang.class));
```

That's it